# MySql Stored Procedure's parameter with the same name as affecting's column, is it possible?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a sequence table with two columns, name, value, and I have a stored procedure for incrementing the value provided the name

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS p_generate_sequence;
delimiter |
CREATE PROCEDURE p_generate_sequence (name VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN
    START TRANSACTION;
    -- Variable "name" equal to column "name", how to reference?
    UPDATE sequences_table SET value = value + 1 WHERE name = name;
    SELECT value FROM sequences_table WHERE name = name;
    COMMIT;
END |
delimiter ;
```

Note the parameter is called "name".

Is there any approach for using a parameter with the same name as the column name of the affected table?

**NOTE:** I'm not interested in change parameter's name, nor even column's name, just to know whether is it possible or not, and how.

Comment: maybe this will help - http://forge.mysql.com/tools/tool.php?id=13

Comment: I feel a bit dumb... very easy, thanks a lot, Matt

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, scope your table column by an alias.

e.g.

```
delimiter //
create procedure foo( id int )
begin
 select * from users u where u.id = id;
end
//

call foo( 123 )
```

returns user id = 123