# MySQL function with query inside it

Tags: mysql, function

I used this mysql function to retrieve the sum of a column's data with passing three parameters. Function return the sum of whole column regardless of where clause. 
I mean that the query inside the function act as it has no where clause and this query works fine when used without function.
Here is the function

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION calculate_customer_loan(customer_id INT, currency VARCHAR(10), type VARCHAR(10)) RETURNS DOUBLE
BEGIN
    DECLARE total DOUBLE;
    SELECT SUM(`amount`) INTO total FROM `deals` WHERE `customer_id` = customer_id AND `currency` = currency AND `type` = type;
    RETURN total;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Any idea!
help me.

Comment: Rename your function parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with parameter names matching column names.  The column names win.

So, name your parameters to avoid ambiguity:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION calculate_customer_loan (
    in_customer_id INT,
    in_currency VARCHAR(10),
    in_type VARCHAR(10)
) RETURNS DOUBLE
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_total DOUBLE;

    SELECT SUM(d.amount) INTO v_total
    FROM deals d
    WHERE d.customer_id = in_customer_id AND
          d.currency = in_currency AND
          d.type = in_type;
    RETURN v_total;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I removed the backticks.  They are not needed and -- more importantly -- they do not distinguish between column names and variable names.

Comment: "The column names win" - I wouldn't say so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715229/mysql-stored-procedures-parameter-with-the-same-name-as-affectings-column-is

Comment: @PaulSpiegel . . . That answer would appear to be incorrect.

Comment: That answer seams to be correct. Here is a simple test: http://rextester.com/JEWVL30269 However I would still use different names.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Isn't there a typo in this answer. You never actually set v_total.